# How to input lowercase letter after shift every time?

Tags: 18.04, input

every time after I "shift" from one input method to another, the first letter I input always is capitalized.
For example, after I "shift" from English input to a Pinyin input method and I want to input "hello", but in fact what I input is "Hello"-whose first letter "h" is capitalized to "H", that's what I want to avoid, namely, I just want to input "hello" instead of "Hello". 
The same problem I will find when I "shift" from Pinyin input to English method.
How to fix this kind of problem?

Comment: Which Program are you using to type Hello? In LibreOffice Tools--> Auto Correct--> AutoCorrect Options... TAB Options Capitalize first letter of every sentence.

Comment: Are you using an IME? How do you switch input methods (keyboard shortcut, mouse,...)?